# Cross-platform C++: convert to/from UTC/local time WITH historical tzdata

Tags: c++, windows, timezone, utc

I need to convert times from UTC to a timezone selected by the user.  I also have to convert from user input in that time zone to store in UTC.

Currently timezones are defined in Olson format ("America/Los Angeles").

A solution was easy on Linux with timegm, but I can not find a cross platform solution (or any solution) that does the exact same thing on Windows.

I can not use Boost.Date_Time (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time.html) because it does not support historical timezone changes such as varying DST periods over the years.  Someone apparently submitted a patch years ago but it does not appear to have been accepted.

The only other solution that seems plausible is to use data and code from: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Has anyone tried this, or do you have a better idea?

Comment: Have you considered [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)?  It has fairly good time zone support.

Comment: I had discarded it because "ICU does not concern itself with either leap seconds or historical behavior".  But I will take a closer look.

Comment: That is with specific regard to UTC/GMT terminology.  There is indeed all of the richness of IANA tzdata in there - unlike Boost.

Comment: Looks like ICU will work.  I had looked at Boost first, and their implementation was supposed to be based off ICU yet didn't have these features.  But ICU does use historical timezone information.  Create an answer and I can select it.  Thanks!

Comment: Link-only answers are usually discouraged on StackOverflow.  Probably best just to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a cross platform, open source C++11/C++14 timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) that wraps the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), including *all* historical data.  The IANA database *is* the currently maintained Olson database.

An example from this library is:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using namespace date;

    auto departure = make_zoned("America/New_York",
                                local_days{dec/30/1978} + 12h + 1min);
    auto flight_length = 14h + 44min;
    auto arrival = make_zoned("Asia/Tehran",
                              departure.get_sys_time() + flight_length);

    std::cout << "departure NYC time:  " << departure << '\n';
    std::cout << "flight time is       " << make_time(flight_length) << '\n';
    std::cout << "arrival Tehran time: " << arrival << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
departure NYC time:  1978-12-30 12:01:00 EST
flight time is       14:44
arrival Tehran time: 1978-12-31 11:45:00 IRST
```

Note the date:  December of 1978.  This *is* historically accurate (as far as timezone handling is concerned).  The paper goes on to demonstrate how the same flight on the next day has a different arrival time because of a timezone change in Tehran.

The example above does not handle leap seconds.  However if you actually do want to handle leap seconds, the library can handle it with a small amount of extra work:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using namespace date;

    auto departure = make_zoned("America/New_York",
                                local_days{dec/31/1978} + 12h + 1min);
    auto departure_utc = to_utc_time(departure.get_sys_time());
    auto flight_length = 14h + 44min;
    auto arrival = make_zoned("Asia/Tehran",
                              to_sys_time(departure_utc + flight_length));

    std::cout << "departure NYC time:  " << departure << '\n';
    std::cout << "flight time is       " << make_time(flight_length) << '\n';
    std::cout << "arrival Tehran time: " << arrival << '\n';
}

departure NYC time:  1978-12-31 12:01:00 EST
flight time is       14:44
arrival Tehran time: 1979-01-01 11:14:59 IRST
```

This is all described in detail at:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

and freely available at:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date